# How to create an interactive pdf outside of InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, template-design, affinity-publisher, canva

I need to create a newsletter template that is easy to use (it will be used by someone with no InDesign experience) and needs to support hyperlinks within the document and to external sources.

So far I've tried Adobe Express but this does not support the links I require, also considered Canva but am finding this difficult to use.

I know I can do what I need to in InDesign but I need a format that is easy for non-designers to use also that will export an Interactive .pdf.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I haven't used Adobe Express before, but it looks a lot like Canva. Canva allows you to add document links or external links, and allows downloading of a PDF.  Try it and see.

Comment: Tag Affinity Publisher suggests that also it could be used. So, use it. In the web there are tutorials of inserting links and setting the PDF export options  to make links to work in PDFs.  Wrong setting causes the links to occur only as a nice blue color in a PDF, but nothing happens. NOTE: A.Publisher is quite as complex for a beginner as all layout design programs.

Comment: Thanks, yes Publisher was mentioned but none of the people involved have any experience in using it, making it less than ideal. Proceeding with Canva. Thanks all